# Meaning of "to have seconds"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm watching Futurama now, and on episode s1e7 there is Zoidberg's quote I cannot understand nor find out the explanation.

The dialog is:

> Amy Wong: Is this salt water?
>   Bender: It's salt with water in it, if that's what you mean.
>   Fry: My vision's fading! I think I'm gonna die!
>   Bender: There was nothing wrong with that food. The salt level was 10%
>   less than a lethal dose.
>   Dr. Zoidberg: Uh oh. I shouldn't have had seconds.

Could anybody explain the meaning of it?

Comment: "seconds" here means "a second helping (of food)"

Comment: This could be answered by consulting a dictionary http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/seconds

Comment: @AlanMunn, thank you, I thought I had to search for idiomatic meaning of "to have seconds". I was wrong, but what should I do with the question?

Comment: Leave it and don't worry about it.

Comment: Of course, in a duel "having a second" means something entirely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means to have a second serving of food

Comment: Hi, your answer was flagged for its length and content. It is not encouraged to post an answer without any research/reference/link that can support it. Please edit your post. You could use the linked definition posted in a comment by Martin Smith above.